# How can I share legend for multiple maps in tmap?

Tags: r, tmap

Running example code from `tmap` library:

```
library("tmap")
tmap_mode("plot")
data(NLD_muni)

tm_shape(NLD_muni) +
  tm_borders() +
  tm_bubbles(size = c("origin_native", "origin_non_west"), legend.size.is.portrait = TRUE)
```

Gives me following map

[image]

All works as advertised, however I'm trying to force `tmap` to use same bubble size on both maps.. and plot only one legend. How could that be achieved?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Size: You need to specify `size.max` to give both variables common reference.

Legend: there is no straightforward way -- you cannot pass `c(TRUE, FALSE)` vector to `legend.size.show`, it's either both or none. You need to use a workaround with custom `grid`.

Code below:

```
library(grid)
library(tmap)
tmap_mode("plot")
data(NLD_muni)

max_size <- max(c(NLD_muni$origin_non_west, NLD_muni$origin_native))

nld_plot_native <- tm_shape(NLD_muni) +
  tm_borders() +
  tm_bubbles(
    size = "origin_native", 
    size.max = max_size, 
    legend.size.is.portrait = TRUE,
    legend.size.show = TRUE
  )

nld_plot_non_west <- tm_shape(NLD_muni) +
  tm_borders() +
  tm_bubbles(
    size = "origin_non_west", 
    size.max = max_size, 
    legend.size.is.portrait = TRUE,
    legend.size.show = FALSE
  )

grid.newpage()
pushViewport(viewport(layout = grid.layout(1, 2)))
print(nld_plot_native, vp = viewport(layout.pos.col = 1))
print(nld_plot_non_west, vp = viewport(layout.pos.col = 2))
```

[image]